# Linux equivalent of Windows Device Manager / DevCon utility?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-manager

I was wondering if there is any Linux equivalent to Windows Device Manager, or the Windows `DevCon` utility (a command line utility with hardware management functionality).

Do drivers even work the same way in Linux?

Comment: Related [What is the equivalent of Windows System Properties or Device Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146621/what-is-the-equivalent-of-windows-system-properties-or-device-manager)

Answer (score 6):

The functionality provided by Windows `devcon` is covered by various facilties and commands in Linux.

The "plug and play" manager of Linux is usually `udev`.  `udev` is responsible for recognizing hardware changes, (possibly) autoloading modules, and creating nodes in `/dev` if needed.  If you wish to do something such as simulate a USB device removal under Linux (something that `devcon` can do), commands that interact with the running `udevd` should be used, I believe.  I haven't done this under Linux but you can start by learning more about `udev`.

`lsmod` will display all currently loaded kernel modules.  Device drivers are one function of a kernel module.  `insmod` will load and start a module if possible, and most of the time cause the device to appear in `/dev`.  `rmmod` does the reverse.  If you execute an `lsmod` you'll notice some modules are dependent on others, `rmmod` won't let you remove a module if something depends on it.  `modprobe` with its options handles dependencies.

Under Linux, modules can also be "built-in" to the kernel, and they won't appear in any module list.  They are immediately and always available the moment the kernel is loaded by the bootloader.  Another option is to place modules in a directory within an "initial ramdisk" (`initrd`) which is also loaded by the bootloader and immediately accessible to the kernel on boot.  "Installing" or 
"updating" device drivers may involve creating a new or updated kernel with the module built-in, or adding/updating it in the initrd if it is not there.  Most distributions provide tools and utilties to do this.

You usually would not have to worry about installing or obtaining a third-party driver unless it is not included in the "official" kernel from kernel.org - since kernel modules (including drivers) are part of the kernel, drivers for every supported device are also included, and usually provided with your distribution.  So needing to install a "manufacturer-provided driver" under Linux isn't terribly common except possibly for video drivers and some wireless chipsets which still have a lot of legal encumbrances with regard to technical information needed by driver developers.

`lshw` can give you most of this information in a tree-like format.  `lspci`, `lsusb`, `lsscsi`, and `lscpu` are also very helpful.  Most busses such as PCI, SCSI, USB, have a lot of userland utilities available in most Linux distributions that you can use to configure and get information of specific classes of devices (example: `hdparm`).  And almost all mentioned in this paragraph, and more, are just frontends to various files and directories in `/proc` and `/sys`; you'll want to use the utilities though in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

Drivers are not same with Windows and Linux. You can under some circumstances load Windows devices drivers into a Linux kernel however.

About Linux device drivers:

Drivers can be complied into the Linux kernel or as modules. If they are modules, they can be (un)loaded on demand.

You can find information about a machines devices with these commands:

```
lspci
lsusb
```

My favorite is

```
lspci -nn
```

for names and numbers.

Have a look at the man pages for the following commands:

```
modprobe
rmmod
lsmod
modinfo
```

In short:

`modprobe` loads a kernel module.

`rmmod` removes kernel modile.

`lsmod` lists the currently loaded modules.

`modinfo` shows info about a specific module.

There are GUI apps as well. KDE has one in it's control center called kinfocenter I think.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Another useful program is `lshw`.

Answer (score 4):

Try on linux the command: **lshw-gtk**, it is the front-end for the **lshw**.

Answer (score 2):

Most device drivers in linux are kernel extension. You can list them with "lsmod", remove them with "rmmod" or load them with "modprobe".

Comment: I think "modprobe -r" is better for removing kernel modules, since it also handles dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in `/sys` for the real device tree that lsusb/lspci are merely showing an abridged tabloid view of.